# Question about rigorous writing of $\varepsilon-N$ proofs.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

When writing an $\varepsilon-N$ proof the definition ends up with $d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon$ for all $n>N_\varepsilon$.

Sometimes, it so happens that the right-hand side of the inequality is an expression of $\varepsilon$, for example $d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon^7+3\varepsilon$.

What is the best way to transform, let's say $d(x_n,l)<f(\varepsilon)$ for all $n>N_\varepsilon$, into the usual  $\varepsilon-N$ proof?

Of course $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$ and also it is probably increasing and continuous.

Comment: Just $f(\epsilon) \rightarrow 0$ is enough to get the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exists $\delta>0$ for arbitary $\varepsilon$ such that $|x|<\delta\Rightarrow f(\delta)<\varepsilon$.

When $d(x_n,l)<f(\delta)$ for all $n>N_\varepsilon$, then $d(x_n,l)<\varepsilon$.